# How can I access the data I got back from shell_exec?

Tags: php, json, shell-exec

I have a php script, then I run it line by line.

I run this line:
`$ip = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));`

I got : `50.198.81.174`

Then I run the next line:

`$php_info = trim(shell_exec("curl ipinfo.io/".$ip));`

I got

```
"""
{\n
  "ip": "50.198.81.174",\n
  "hostname": "50-198-81-174-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net",\n
  "city": "Braintree",\n
  "region": "Massachusetts",\n
  "country": "US",\n
  "loc": "42.2038,-71.0022",\n
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",\n
  "postal": "02184"\n
}
"""
```

I'm trying to access the result in it, for example the **city**

`echo ($php_info['city']);`

I couldn't. :(

How do I properly access them?

Comment: That's close to JSON but looks not right.  I ran that Curl and got good output though, try: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the *wrong* command. You should use `exec();` It has a built-in argument for outputting the results into an *array* so that you dont have to do that yourself with a bunch of code. Then you can just parse the array element that has the info you want.

```
<?php
$info = exec("curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8",$arrInfo);
print_r($arrInfo);
```

//outputs

```
Array ( [0] => { [1] => "ip": "8.8.8.8", [2] => "hostname": "google-public-dns-a.google.com", 
[3] => "city": "Mountain View", 
[4] => "region": "California", 
[5] => "country": "US", 
[6] => "loc": "37.3860,-122.0838", 
[7] => "org": "AS15169 Google Inc.", 
[8] => "postal": "94040" [9] => } )
```

OR you can just use **JSON_DECODE** and continue to use shell_exec(); This will get you the *exact* values in the array.

```
<?php

$info = shell_exec("curl ipinfo.io/8.8.8.8");

print_r(json_decode($info,true));
?>
```

//output

```
Array ( [ip] => 8.8.8.8 [hostname] => google-public-dns-a.google.com 
[city] => Mountain View [region] => California 
[country] => US 
[loc] => 37.3860,-122.0838 
[org] => AS15169 Google Inc. [postal] => 94040 )
```

Json_decode with the true flag will output it in to an associative array.

Comment: Very nice answer. I will take your advice. Thank-you very much.

Comment: @ihue thanks, I suggest using my updated code using json_decode. It will get you an array with the exact values.

Comment: I agree with you 100%. It's exactly what I am using. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

i think this will help you.
To access each specification you just need use index of list

```
<?php
$str = '"""
{\n
  "ip": "50.198.81.174",\n
  "hostname": "50-198-81-174-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net",\n
  "city": "Braintree",\n
  "region": "Massachusetts",\n
  "country": "US",\n
  "loc": "42.2038,-71.0022",\n
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",\n
  "postal": "02184"\n
}
"""';
$find = array('"""', '\n', '{', '}');
$str = str_replace($find, '', $str);
$str = str_replace('",', "-*-", $str);

$str = explode("-*-", $str);

$list[] = "";

for($i=0;$i<count($str);$i++)
{

    $str_temp = str_replace('"', '', $str);
    $str_temp = explode(":", $str_temp[$i]);
    $str_temp[0] = str_replace("\n", "", $str_temp[0]);
    $str_temp[1] = str_replace("\n", "", $str_temp[1]);
    $list[trim($str_temp[0])] = $str_temp[1];

}
echo $list['city']."<hr>";
echo $list['country']."<hr>";
echo $list['region']."<hr>";
echo $list['org']."<hr>";
var_dump($list);
```

For example $list['city'] will return the name of city.