# How to remove leading and trailing characters from a string?

Tags: php, trim, double-quotes

I have a crooked data `"""" { ... } """`
I want to polish it out a little bit.

How do I take off `"` before my open `{` and also take off the `"` after my closing `}` ?

---

**Example**

```
"""
{\n
  "ip": "50.198.81.174",\n
  "hostname": "50-198-81-174-static.hfc.comcastbusiness.net",\n
  "city": "Braintree",\n
  "region": "Massachusetts",\n
  "country": "US",\n
  "loc": "42.2038,-71.0022",\n
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, Inc.",\n
  "postal": "02184"\n
}
"""
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: All of them or only the matching?

Comment: In the first case, trim() is perfect, see @Brians comment

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976328/how-can-i-access-the-data-i-got-back-from-shell-exec I don't get that output when I run the curl command.  I get actual JSON that can be decoded with json_decode().

Comment: @AbraCadaver : wow ! how do you get different data than me ? Did you run it on a Mac Terminal like me ?

Comment: No I ran it on Debian terminal and I get correct JSON.

Comment: So I think, this should work fine, when I host it on the production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function in `PHP`:

```
$trimmed = trim('"""" { ... } """', '"');
echo $trimmed;
```

**OUTPUT:**

> { ... }

You can also use `rtrim` (removes from right side) and `ltrim` (removes from left side).

Comment: I've tried `$ip = trim(shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com"));
$php_info = shell_exec('curl ipinfo.io/'.$ip);
trim($php_info, '"');
dd($php_info);

`

Comment: I got the same result. Do u know why ? ?

Comment: Try to check what's in this: `shell_exec("dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com")`